# JSON Web service with ASP.NET - from a frustrated php guy

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, web-services, asmx

I've been a PHP developer for a few years now and have developed at least a dozen APIs using JSON. Create a url that does a task, and return json_encode($array)... Piece of cake...right?

Now, I used to be a .net developer a while back (about 8 yrs ago) and I've been given the task to develop a small api/webservice for a client. I've been doing some reading on WCF and have been tinkering with it for a few hours now. My question is.. Is it me or is it incredibly over complicated to just run a RESTFUL query and return a block of JSON? In other words, why can't I just create an ASPX page that takes an array and encodes it as JSON and spits it out? Does it really HAVE to be WCF? Or even ASMX  for that matter? Feels like overkill? No? Can someone offer a valid reson on why I need to go through the pain of WCF if I'm making a simple service that returns a few lines of JSON?

Comment: In a simple ASMX service, all you'd need to do is return the array - ASP.NET will automatically JSON serialize it for you. You wouldn't even have to do the equivalent of calling `json_encode()` on it. So, that's not very complicated. If you look, you'll find examples of using JavaScriptSerializer to do that directly in ASPX pages, but you *should not do that*. A WebForms ASPX page always runs through its entire page life cycle, even if you only use it to `Response.Write` some JSON. You'll be incurring a non-trivial performance penalty if you go that route.

Comment: There can choices to make with Microsoft technology as it tends to evolve in multiple directions. You might like to check out some of Glenn Block's and/or Rob Conery's conference videos on recent REST based developments at MS and simplifying WCF. Eg: "tech ed NA 2010 - WPH306 - Occassionally Connected Applications", "MIX11 - FRM14 - Glenn Block - Web APIs, There's a URL for that". PS: This question crossed my radar on the moderator tool being flagged as not a clear question. May help to rephrase question from subjective pain observation to what is the simplest approach to xxx (with specifics).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`WebMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

**Script:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {        
    // alert(msg.d);
  }
});
```